# fail to load SQS message

Tags: java, spring

language: Java 
Framework: Spring boot
dependency: spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging:1.2.1.RELEASE

When I try to use

```
@SqsListener(value = "${queuename}",deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
```

to listen AWS queue for HK region, somehow it cannot read the queue message.

It is a program run on AWS EC2. It can run normally just no message.
other setting should be use default.

Do anyone know why the sqs listener cannot read the message? thanks.

Comment: Did you configure aws client and sqs container factory? Without a complete setup, it would be hard to tell why it's not working.

Comment: I dont have set aws client and sqs container factory. I should be use the default setting

Comment: and it can get message from queue when using URL e.g. https://sqs.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com/{accountid}/{queuename}

Comment: You can check SimpleMessageListenerContainer, I can't provide more details without seeing your code.